# The option mapstruct.defaultComponentModel is not being recognized

Tags: java, maven, mapstruct

I have this configuration in my `pom.xml` file:

```xml
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
<!-- more pom code -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>2.6.6</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>
                            -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                        </arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But I still get the warning during building `java: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[mapstruct.defaultComponentModel]'`

I believe my configuration follows the [Mapstruct documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/)

Why is the option not recognized?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74853001/warning-the-following-options-were-not-recognized-by-any-processor-for-mapstr) doesn't appear to be helpful

Answer (score 1):

This warning can be safely ignore : you can manage to not show this error anymore with a simple configuration tag and adding a default profile inside
like :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                        <version>0.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <compilerArg>
                        -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                    </compilerArg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However you'll get another issue when testing, some mappers will not be implementated without the package stage from maven.
My advice is to simply ignore this warning